# how do i still get a reference from the game object after it get destroyed?

Tags: unity, c#

This is the script from the game object that will be soon get deleted.

```
    public class Firstboss : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int healthPoints = 3;
    public bool firstTriggered;
    public bool Firstdied;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "circle")
        {
            healthPoints--;
            if(healthPoints <= 2)
            {
                firstTriggered = true;
            }

            if(healthPoints <= 0)
            {
                Firstdied = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But after "FirstDied = true" it will pass on to my other script

```
 [SerializeField] Firstboss _firstBossScipt;
[SerializeField] GameObject _firstBoss;
[SerializeField] GameObject _FirstFall;
[SerializeField] GameObject _FirstFelll_secondPhase;

 void FirstWave_Second()
{
    if(Time.time > _nextSpawnTime_First_SecondPhase)
    {
        _nextSpawnTime_First_SecondPhase = Time.time + SpawnBetween_First_SecondPhase;
        Vector2 SpawnPosFirst = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1.80f, 1.70f), cameraScreenWrap.y);
        Instantiate(_FirstFelll_secondPhase, SpawnPosFirst, Quaternion.identity);

        if (_firstBoss != null)
        {
            if (_firstBossScipt.firstTriggered == true)
            {
                _FirstFall.SetActive(false);
                _FirstFelll_secondPhase.SetActive(true);
                CancelInvoke("FirstWave");

            }
            if (_firstBossScipt.Firstdied == true)
            {
                _FirstFelll_secondPhase.SetActive(false);
                Invoke("SecondWaveLeft", 0f);
                Invoke("SecondWaveRight", 0f);
                Instantiate(_secondBoss, new Vector2(0.5764521f, -1.73f), Quaternion.identity);
                Destroy(_firstBoss.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now my _firstboss bool wont get called because I have destroyed my game object. Is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: Can you clearify a bit more? your if statement says *do this if _firstBoss isn't null* and your question is how to make it true after making _firstBoss destroyed. Tell us why you still want to call it after the boss get destroyed

Comment: because i have put a bool over at that boss script. But if I destroyed the game object, it destroys the bool and whatever  put in that script too. So I can't make a reference to that script or get acknowledged by it too.

Comment: Maybe you could move the logic to a wave manager? It keeps track how many enemies you killed and/ or boss monster?

Comment: You can't get a reference to a destroyed object.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need another script to be your manager of this variable, like a "GameManager", and there you control if it is true or false.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool firstDied;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
            
    }
}
```

```
public GameManager gameManagerScript;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "circle")
    {
        healthPoints--;

        if (healthPoints <= 2)
        {
            firstTriggered = true;
        }

        if (healthPoints <= 0)
        {
            gameManagerScript.Firstdied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

That way you never lose the status of that variable, even if your object has been destroyed.

PS: To make it easier: you don't need to pull reference from the gameManager every time you need to use it, you can use a "Singleton" in it and just call it in every new script you have.
(remembering that you can only have 1 gameObject containing the script that uses singleton in the scene)

**Singleton Tutorial:**

https://gamedevbeginner.com/singletons-in-unity-the-right-way/